# How to sample a dataframe column within a group without reordering of rows?

Tags: r, plyr

I have a R dataframe d2 with two columns i.e., "class" and "entry". Where "class" is categorical variable and "entry" is continuous given by

```
d2

   class entry
1      1     1
2      2     2
3      3     3
4      4     4
5      1     5
6      2     6
7      3     7
8      4     8
9      1     9
10     2    10
11     3    11
12     4    12
13     1    13
14     2    14
15     3    15
16     4    16
17     1    17
18     2    18
19     3    19
20     4    20
```

I Now want to sample "entry" column within the a group given as

```
ddply(d2,.(class),function(x) x[sample(nrow(x)),])

   class entry
1      1     9
2      1     1
3      1     5
4      1    13
5      1    17
6      2    14
7      2    10
8      2     2
9      2     6
10     2    18
11     3    15
12     3    19
13     3     7
14     3     3
15     3    11
16     4    16
17     4    20
18     4    12
19     4     8
20     4     4
```

It is clearly visible that desired results are obtained but order of the "class" variable is also changed compared to original data d2.
I want to get same output without reordering rows of "class" variable of d2.
Thanks

Comment: Could you please tell me why that function is not working?  It works for me though

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(d2)[, entry := sample(entry), by = class]
```

---

or use `ave` from `base R`

```
d2$entry <- with(d2, ave(entry, class, FUN = sample))
```

Comment: Thankyou akrun, I tried second one it worked for me. Do have have any way to get indices of locations that have been replaced.

Comment: @user96368  If you need the indices, then you may need `setDT(d2)[, ind := sample(.I), by = class]` then use this `ind` to order i.e. `d2[(ind)]`

Comment: hi akrun, your first solution also method worked fine for me. But i found a strange problem with the use of the function. I have used your function in a different user defined function to receive output back. The problem is that my original variable is also replaced by output. nd=randomise_frag(d)

randomise_frag <- function(data)
{
  
  library(data.table)
  setDT(data)[, start.D_gr1_f2. := sample(data$start.D_gr1_f2.), by = data$seqnames.D_gr1_f1.]
  setDT(data)[, ind := sample(.I), by = data$seqnames.D_gr1_f1.]
  data[(ind)]
  return(data)
}

Comment: @user96368  why you are using `$` if you want to subset inside function then use `[[`.  Also within `data.table`, you don't need to specify the objname$columnname

Comment: Please see below: this code:   #####     
'randomise_frag <- function(data)
{
  
  library(data.table)
  setDT(data)[, entry := sample(entry), by = class]
  setDT(data)[, ind := sample(.I), by = class]
  data[(ind)]
  return(data)
}

#########
d=data.frame(class=rep(c(1,2,3,4), 5),entry=seq(1:20))
nd=randomise_frag(d)'

Comment: @user96368  Perhaps you need `randomise_frag <- function(data) { 
        data1 <- as.data.table(data);
        v1 <- data1[, sample(.I), by = class]$V1;
        print(v1);
        data1[, entry := entry[v1]][];
          }; randomise_frag(d)`

Comment: Sorry @akrun, on close examination of results i found that, this trick is not giving desired output. If you will run this code steps you will find v1 is giving sampled induces of entry but classes get clustered and these clustered induces are not in order as i desired.